# How to call back the same window!? PYQT5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I spent all day debugging and stripping my project to fix this issue.

I have a help window(Help_ui class) which should open if the text.txt is not found and the main window(Main class)which has a QTextEdit box which should print "Hello".
The problem is that when I call the Main window from the Help_ui class it doesn't print "Hello", but it does if I call it from the logic.

Why is doing this, does it open another instance of that windows and not the proper window?

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys
from pathlib import Path
from ui_files import mainWindow
from ui_files import help_ui


text = "Hello"

class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, mainWindow.Ui_mainWindow):
    def __init__(self, text):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.mainTextEdit.setText(text)


class Help_ui(QtWidgets.QDialog, help_ui.Ui_help):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.close_btn.clicked.connect(self.close)

        self.form = Main(None)
        self.form.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = Main(text)

    my_file = Path("file.txt")
    if my_file.is_file():
        form.show()
    else:            
        help_window = Help_ui()
        help_window.show()

    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens is that the instance `form` is different from the instance `self.form`, in the first you pass as a parameter `text`, instead in the second `None`.

Must be change `self.form = Main(None)` to `self.form = Main(text)`

Comment: Yes, it work for this example. I remember doing this in my code but didn't work so I deliberately set it to None.